# Conversion of Binary predicate with existensial quantifiers into propositional logic formulas

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

How to convert sentence with Existential quantification into sentence without quantifiers given domain D={3,4} ?

I found the solution for ∃Zq(Z) => q(1) U q(2)

I also found the solution but not sure whether it is correct or wrong for:

∃X∀Yp(X,Y)≡(∀Yp(3,Y))∨(∀Yp(4,Y))

≡‌​(p(3,3)∧p(3,4))∨(p(4‌​,3))∧p(4,4))

Is the above computation correct?

Also I am stuck when it comes to conversion of binary predicate: ∀X∃Y p(X, Y )

Comment: Yes, those are correct. ... so why don't you convert that last one step by step as well? That is, $\forall X \exists Y P(X,Y) = \exists Y P(3,Y) \land \exists P(4,Y) = ...$

Comment: See the previous similar post: [conversion-first-order-logic-formula-into-propositional-logic-formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465449/conversion-first-order-logic-formula-into-propositional-logic-formula).

Comment: @Bram28 So the expansion is: ∀X∃YP(X,Y)=∃YP(3,Y)∧∃P(4,Y)=​(p(3,3)∨p(3,4))∧(p(4‌​,3)∨p(4,4)) .. and also how do I remove all the braces in case I want to express it as continuous formula? like can I express it as p(3,3)∨p(3,4)∧(p(4‌​,3)∨p(4,4)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, yes thank you very much! but I have one more doubt regarding this that I have posted above

Comment: @confucious Your expansion is correct, but you *cannot* drop those parentheses! Something like  $P \land (Q \lor R)$ is not equivalent to $(P \land Q) \lor R$, and so you really need to use parenthese when you have a combination of $\land$'s and $\lor$'s.

Comment: But cant we use distributive law? (A∨B)∧ C=A∧ C∨B∧ C

Comment: @confucious Unless you give priority of $\land$ over $\lor$ (and many logic textbooks do not), you still need parentheses, and so it should be $(A \land C) \lor (B \land C)$

Comment: http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~japaridz/Archive/1300/lect1.2/sld009.htm